# Integrate monomials over unit circle

Tags: integration

I'd like to integrate monomials $x^{2m} y^{2n}$ over the unit circle analytically, and while I got a correct expression, it's not symmetric w.r.t. $m$ and $n$, which is weird. (Btw, if one of the exponents is odd, the value of the integral is 0, hence the $2$s.)

Here is what I did: I'd like to calculate the value of
$$
I = \int_0^{2\pi} \cos^{2m}\theta \sin^{2n}\theta\:\text{d}\theta.
$$
We get
$$
\begin{split}
I 
&= \int_0^{2\pi} \left(1-\sin^2\theta\right)^m \sin^{2n}\theta\:\text{d}\theta\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{m} (-1)^k \binom{m}{k} \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^{2(k+n)}\theta \:\text{d}\theta.
\end{split}
$$
For any $\mu\in\mathbb{N}$, we have
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^{2\mu}\theta \:\text{d}\theta
= 2\pi \frac{(\mu-1)!!}{\mu!!}
= 2\pi \frac{(2\mu)!}{\left(2^{\mu} \mu!\right)^2},
$$
so eventually
$$
I = 2\pi \sum_{k=0}^{m} (-1)^k \binom{m}{k} \frac{\left(2(k+n)\right)!}{\left(2^{k+n} (k+n)!\right)^2}.
$$
Swapping $m$ and $n$ doesn't change the value – as it should – but it's impossible to see this from the formula. This makes me think that there is a better way to express $I$.

Any hints?

Comment: Do you know the beta function? Another option would be to use Stokes' theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \cos^{2m}(x) \sin^{2n}(x) dx
&= 4 \int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^{2m}(x) \sin^{2n}(x) dx \\
&= 2 \mathrm{B}\left(\frac{2n+1}{2},\frac{2m+1}{2}\right) \\
&= 2 \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{2m+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(m+n+1)}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion would be to use Euler's formulae. Modulo erreurs it should go like this:

$$ \cos^{2m}  \theta \; \sin^{2n} \theta = 
 \frac{1}{4^{m+n}} \left( e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta} \right)^{2m}
\left( e^{i\theta} -e^{-i\theta} \right)^{2n} (-1)^n =
$$
$$\frac{1}{4^{m+n}}\sum_k\sum_\ell 
\left( \begin{matrix} 2m \\ k \end{matrix} \right) 
\left( \begin{matrix} 2n \\ \ell \end{matrix} \right)
e^{2i\theta \; (k+\ell-m-n)} (-1)^{n-\ell}
$$
Integrating only gives contributions when $k+l=m+n$ (and the last sign is in fact symmetric in $n-\ell=m-k$)